# Wacom Tablet Not Showing Up in Settings (18.04)

Tags: mate, tablet, wacom

Okay, so I originally asked about my new tablet here - [16.04 won't recognize Wacom Intuos Tablet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049432/16-04-wont-recognize-wacom-intuos-tablet) - but ended up finding out that my tablet WAS recognized when running the Live CD.  Then my hard drive crashed and I ended up having to completely reinstall everything from scratch (thank goodness for backups!).  I really liked MATE so tried that, but could not get it to recognize the tablet at all again.  So I now have the vanilla 18.04.  The tablet is recognized and I can use the stylus to move the mouse around the screen, however the settings menu does NOT recognize it at all or allow me to customize it or anything.

Further Googling has shown several official bug reports on this issue, but I haven't found any solutions.  I didn't know if I was just missing these or if the reason was because they didn't exist.  Since this issue appears to have been around since at least 16.04, it seems like they would have figured something out by now, but maybe not?

PS: I still much prefer MATE and if there is ANY way I can get the tablet to work in MATE, I would very much prefer that to running plain Ubuntu!

EDIT: Adding this in case it might help...

```
/usr/bin/libwacom-list-local-devices
[Device]
Name=Wacom Serial Tablet WACf004
DeviceMatch=serial:0000:0000;
Class=ISDV4
Width=0
Height=0
IntegratedIn=Display;System;
Styli=0xfffff;0xffffe;

[Features]
Reversible=false
Stylus=true
Ring=false
Ring2=false
Touch=false
TouchSwitch=false
StatusLEDs=
NumStrips=0
Buttons=0
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem when upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 from 16.04.
The following steps worked for me.

1. Removing the existing `xserver-xorg-input-wacom`
2. Installing the [latest input wacom from source](https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/wiki/Installing-input-wacom-from-source)

Answer (score 0):

( couldn't comment, so, had to answer but this is more of a comment than that. Though I would be happy to help you out.)

I am using a Wacom Intuos Draw with Ubuntu Mate. Works out of the box. Though I did have to learn to change its pressure sensitivity, screen area, and tablet area. I don't really know why it might be happening to you but maybe the following will help to see what the problem might be.

================================================================================

Connect your tablet with PC and open terminal.

To list the graphic tablet and pen connected:

```
xsetwacom --list devices
```

EXAMPLE OUTPUT:

```
Wacom Intuos S 2 Pen stylus         id: 9   type: STYLUS    
Wacom Intuos S 2 Pad pad            id: 10  type: PAD
```

> If this fails that would mean your pc isn't detecting your tablet.

Now type:

```
xsetwacom --get "Wacom Intuos S 2 Pen stylus" area
```

> Replace ***Wacom Intuos S 2 Pen stylus*** with your device name.

The output should be (for example):

```
0 0 15200 9500
```

Or in a similar format. The *15200* is your **tablet width** and the *9500* is the **tablet height**.

> If this shows something maybe like: 0 0 0 0. That would mean that you need to change the tablet area.
>
> Follow this link to change the tablet area and/or screen area (also
>   know many other cool tablet settings too):
>   https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wacom_tablet#Adjusting_aspect_ratios

Next type this in:

```
xsetwacom --get "Wacom Intuos S 2 Pen stylus" all
```

I have provided my results (of a working tablet). Maybe compare them to yours and see what could be the problem. It would be best if you could update the question with the outputs from these codes. I would like a look at them.

```
Option "Area" "0 0 15200 9500"
Button: Actions are not supported by xorg.conf. Try shell format (-s) instead.
Button: Actions are not supported by xorg.conf. Try shell format (-s) instead.
Button: Actions are not supported by xorg.conf. Try shell format (-s) instead.
Button: Actions are not supported by xorg.conf. Try shell format (-s) instead.
Option "DebugLevel" "0"
Option "CommonDBG" "0"
Option "Suppress" "2"
Option "RawSample" "4"
Option "PressCurve" "0 0 100 100"
Option "Mode" "Absolute"
Option "TPCButton" "off"
Option "Touch" "off"
Property 'Wacom Hardware Touch Switch' does not exist on device.
Option "Gesture" "off"
Option "ZoomDistance" "0"
Option "ScrollDistance" "0"
Option "TapTime" "250"
Property 'Wacom Proximity Threshold' does not exist on device.
Option "Rotate" "none"
Property 'Wacom Wheel Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Wheel Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Wheel Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Wheel Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Wheel Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Wheel Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Strip Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Strip Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Strip Buttons' does not exist on device.
Property 'Wacom Strip Buttons' does not exist on device.
Option "Threshold" "26"
Option "Serial" "0"
Option "PressureRecalibration" "on"
Option "PanScrollThreshold" "1300"
```

Hope this helps in someway.