# Wacom tablet does not show up in settings, Ubuntu 18

Tags: tablet, wacom

I have a Wacom pen tablet small using Ubuntu 18.  The tablet works but I can not setup the buttons because the table does not show in settings.  In Ubuntu 20 on same laptop (Lenovo 14 flex) the settings do show.  I have logged in using Wayland because otherwise I show no settings for Appearances.

Any suggestions?

garyk

You may also check this thread
[Wacom Tablet Not Showing Up in Settings (18.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065150/wacom-tablet-not-showing-up-in-settings-18-04/1383050?noredirect=1#comment2384877_1383050)

Comment: Ubuntu 18?  Ubuntu 20?  There are no such release; do you mean Ubuntu Core 18 & Ubuntu Core 20? as they the *year* format signifies different products to the far more common *year.month* products; as 18 & 20 are *snap* only products, but 18.04 & 20.04 are *deb* based products that can also use *snap* packages.  Please clarify your release details.

Comment: 18.04 and 20.04

Comment: Please correct your question then, as Ubuntu has had products using the *year* since 2016; they are different products (less powerful, but that's an advantage for less powerful devices, appliances & fast cloud spin-up).   18 != 18.04 etc.  18 & 20 are not designed for desktop usage but use as servers only; 18.04 & 20.04 are for desktops or more powerful servers.